# How can I get flask to run correctly in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

**The Problem:**

I have moved over to Visual Studio Code in order to try to learn to program in a real IDE, however I am low in experience.

**What I have done:**

I have done the following to get it up and running:

```
Installed:
  VS Code,
  Python, 
  Postgres,
  PGAdmin
  pip
```

*I have:*

- Changed the path of python following a tutorial.
- Installed flask, flask-session and SQLAlchemy.
- Used the following "set FLASK_APP=application.py" and "set FLASK_DEBUG=1" and also "set DATABASE_URL= url of database" both in cmd and in visual studio terminal

**The Error Message**

However whenever I run `flask run` I get the following error message in the CMD

```
"flask no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable"
```

In visual studio I get this error message when I run 'flask run':

```
flask : El término 'flask' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si
escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ flask run
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flask:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**The Question:**

I am using Windows 10. How can I get this working?

Comment: It might be helpful to know the english version of this error, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imp: In Windows 10: Visual studio's integrated terminal is PowerShell. Whereas it was cmd.exe for earlier.

Do:

1. On Command Prompt:

   set FLASK_APP=application.py
2. On powershell

   $env:FLASK_APP = "application.py"

`python -m flask run` . Try to use this and if this will not work you have to install flask using `pip install flask` or `pip3 install flask` in your local .

then use `flask run`

For more info check:
https://pypi.org/project/Flask/

Comment: should i do this in cmd or visual

Comment: Visual's terminal you can use. To open it press Ctrl+` .

Comment: this doesnt work unfortunately getting the same response

Comment: python -m flask run . Try to use this and if this will not work you have to install flask using pip install flask in your local . If you have pip3 installed, use pip3 install flask.

Comment: Sofar this would be working how could i get it so that the database url is set in with similar commands would $DATABASE_URL = "url to database" work?

Comment: can you paste the exact log? I think you need to mention a database url somewhere. Which you can do using set DATABASE_URL = "url to database" .

Comment: Use set DATABASE_URL = "url to database". for example : 
set DATABASE_URL=""postgres://user:password@server_ip:5432/table_name""

Comment: within visual studio

Comment: https://docs.cs50.net/ocw/web/projects/1/project1.html -> check point 5 which states to set a database_url -> "Set the environment variable DATABASE_URL to be the URI of your database, which you should be able to see from the credentials page on Heroku."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216453/discussion-between-sanket-singh-and-kwsswart).

Comment: You can also set all of this in your `launch.json` so that it's saved in your project to make it easier to run later. See the [Flask debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_flask-debugging) details and/or the [Flask tutorial for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask).

Answer (score 0):

If you have not installed flask using `$ pip install` then the problem could be that flask is not added as a PATH environment variable.

Try adding flask to your env variables. If this doesn't work then try running `$ python -m flask run` as a temporary workaround.

Comment: I have not setup an environment because didnt think needed to... I just have python installed and used pip to install libraries directly?

Comment: yes after following the above to set the flask app to application.py all i have now is its saying database_url not set